# Logstash - Solr Integration

Tags: solr, logstash, iso8601

Below is my actual log,

```
--2019-05-09 06:49:05.590 -TRACE 6293 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.s.s.service.MessageLogServiceImpl      : [41a6811cbc1c66eda0e942712a12a003d6bf4654b3edb6d24bf159b592afc64f1557384545548] Event => Message Failure Identified : INVALID_STRUCTURE
```

My given grok filter pattern,

```
match => {
         "message" => "--%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} -%{LOGLEVEL:level} (?<pid>\d+) --- \[(?<thread>[^\]]+)] (?<classname>[\w.]+)\s+: \[(?<token>[^\]]+)] Event \=> Message Failure Identified : (?<code>[\w]+)"
     }
```

After doing some adding/removing desired filed below is my tokenized form,

```
{
   "code" => "INVALID_STRUCTURE",
  "event" => "message_failure",
  "token" => "41a6811cbc1c66eda0e942712a12a003d6bf4654b3edb6d24bf159b592afc64f1557384545548",
"logtime" => "2019-05-09 06:49:05.590"
}
```

Now I want to send it to solr, but while sending this is giving me the warning,

[WARN ][logstash.outputs.solrhttp] An error occurred while indexing: undefined method `iso8601' for nil:NilClass

I think it related to "logtime" field since that is the only portion which deals with ISO8601. Nothing extra information found in the logs. What is the problem here?

Comment: Do you have the complete error log? NilClass errors seems to often be caused by other underlying issues.

Comment: Where to get the complete log from?

Comment: I'm guessing there are more lines your logstash log than the single `WARN` you included in your question?

Comment: complete logs can be found at ...\logstash-6.5.4\logs in the file "logstash-plain"

Comment: Even from the log, I can see only the same line appeared number of times and nothing else

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the answer. Thanks
[this blog](https://medium.com/@sreekantht/indexing-log-files-to-solr-using-logstash-5aad3aa3dba)

Logstash will use a ruby library called Rsolr for connecting to Solr. Logstash will install the latest version of Rsolr, but latest Rsolr has a bub with timestamp datatype which will prevent indexing to Solr. To prevent this we will have to manually install the working version of Rsolr.

Changed the default rsolr plugin as mentioned in the post and everything started working